# Reorder dataframe by column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the following df:

| order by this | column1 | column2 | column n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | abc | def | ghi |
| def | def | ghi | jkl |
| ghi | ghi | jkl | nan |
| jkl | mno | nan | nan |
| mno | nan | nan | nan |

--> One column with a complete set of unique values

--> Several columns with a subset of values. These columns have a different length and are thus 'stacked' to the top.

**What I want is to use the values in the first column to reorder the values of the other columns, ie match them against first column.**

Expected outcome:

| order by this | column1 | column2 | column n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | abc | nan | nan |
| def | def | def | nan |
| ghi | ghi | ghi | ghi |
| jkl | nan | jkl | jkl |
| mno | mno | nan | nan |

I guess I can iterrows through 'order by this' and then use loc and something to fill with nan's? Is there a better way?

Comment: The logic is unclear, can you elaborate?

Comment: Tried to clarify, hope that helps @mozway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As what you want is equivalent to checking whether each value from the "order" column is present in the other columns, you could simply do:

```
df.apply(lambda s: df['order'].where(df['order'].isin(s)))
```

output:

```
  order column1 column2 column_n
0   abc     abc     NaN      NaN
1   def     def     def      NaN
2   ghi     ghi     ghi      ghi
3   jkl     NaN     jkl      jkl
4   mno     mno     NaN      NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not getting it, but shouldn't a simple .sort_values () do that? The fact that some NaN are present seems not relevant...

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html

Comment: Maybe I'm not using this correctly, but the way I understand it, sort_values simply orders the existing structure, it basically sorts one column and keeps the associated values of the original df. I'd need to reorder the entire df instead of reordering the original structure